# C++ function previously declared

Tags: c++, compilation, redeclare

I'm making a battleships program for a coursework piece and I was debugging the player's deployment I hit an error that I can't or find a solution to which is:

```
bb.cpp:12: error: previous declaration of ‘int vert(int*, std::string)’
```

I've searched through my code for any previous references to int vert but couldnt find anything.

Here is the function prototypes

```
//game function prototypes

int deploy();  
int firing();  
int gridupdte();  
int win = 0;  
int vert(int *x, string sa);  
int hor(int *y, string s);  
int check();
```

Here is function vert:

```
int vert(*shipx, shiptype) //Calculates where the bow of the ship should be (the pointy bit)  
{  
    int shiplen;  
    int bow;

    switch(shiptype) // Determines the length to add to the y co-ordinate
    {
        case "cv" : shiplen = 5; break;
        case "ca" : shiplen = 4; break;
        case "dd" : shiplen = 3; break;
        case "ss" : shiplen = 3; break;
        case "ms" : shiplen = 2; break;
    }

    bow = *shipx + shiplen;

    *shipx = bow;

    return *shipx;
}

int hor (*shipy, shiptype) //Calculates where the bow of the ship should be (the pointy bit)
{
    int shiplen;
    int bow;

    switch(shiptype) // Determines the length to add to the x co-ordinate
    {
        case "cv" : shiplen = 5; break;
        case "ca" : shiplen = 4; break;
        case "dd" : shiplen = 3; break;
        case "ss" : shiplen = 3; break;
        case "ms" : shiplen = 2; break;
    }

    bow = *shipy + shiplen;

    *shipy = bow;

    return *shipy;
}
```

I am aware of other errors in the comipiling of the whole of the code.

Comment: "error: previous declaration of ..." usually comes with another line of error message. The first line (which you didn't include here) tells *what* the error is, and the second line (which you did copy here) tells *where* the error is. The other line would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`int vert(*shipx, shiptype) { .. }` doesn't tell the types of the parameters.

You neglected to tell us the full error (which spans multiple lines), but I suspect it said that the previous declaration *does not match* the definition.

Write:

```
int vert(int* shipx, string shiptype) { .. }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the types and names of the parameters in a function definition:

```
int vert (int *shipx, string shiptype) {
...
}
```

You should also make the parameter names match between the prototypes and definitions.

Answer (score 0):

This post doesn't really address the error which you've quoted. But there is one more problem with your code which I want to point out, suggesting you a solution for it as well.

In C++, `switch-case` can have only integral constant, not string literal.

So this is wrong:

```
switch(shiptype) // Determines the length to add to the x co-ordinate
{
    case "cv" : shiplen = 5; break;
    case "ca" : shiplen = 4; break;
    case "dd" : shiplen = 3; break;
    case "ss" : shiplen = 3; break;
    case "ms" : shiplen = 2; break;
}
```

This wouldn't compile.

I would suggest you to define an enum `ShipType`, as:

```
enum ShipType
{
    cv,
    ca,
    dd,
    ss,
    ms
};
```

And then declare `shiptype` of type `ShipType`, so that you can write this:

```
switch(shiptype) // Determines the length to add to the x co-ordinate
{
    case cv : shiplen = 5; break;
    case ca : shiplen = 4; break;
    case dd : shiplen = 3; break;
    case ss : shiplen = 3; break;
    case ms : shiplen = 2; break;
}
```

Comment: "I am aware of other errors in the comipiling of the whole of the code." This is not the error being asked about.

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm a bit confused. It doesn't tell which error he is aware of!

Comment: He's asking about the one for which he quotes the compiler error.

Comment: @Tomalak: Hmm...but still that sentence doesn't tell which error he is aware of, though I've to agree that my post doesn't really address the error he has quoted. And if he didn't mention the type of parameters, its not likely that he would be aware of this error.

Answer (score 0):

`int vert(int *shipx, std::string shiptype)` should be what the definition should look like in the third gray box, change `hor` also